# Create function for createElement that accepts more parameters

Tags: javascript, dom

I am interested if there are any chances to make this code shorter.

```js
let event = document.createElement("div")
event.classList.add("event")

let time = document.createElement("div")
time.classList.add("eventTime")
time.textContent = "something"

let timep = document.createElement("p")
timep.classList.add("timep")

let info = document.createElement("div")
info.classList.add("eventInfo")

let summary = document.createElement("h1")
summary.classList.add("eventSummary")

let organizer = document.createElement("p")

organizer.classList.add("eventOrganizer")

time.appendChild(timep)

info.appendChild(summary)
info.appendChild(organizer)

event.appendChild(time)
event.appendChild(info)
document.getElementById("event").appendChild(event)
```

```html
<div id="event"> Hello </div>
```

Could this be written in a shorter version for example

```js
function elementCreation(name, style) {
  return document.createElement(name).classList.add(style)
}
let event = elementCreation("div", "event")
let time = elementCreation("h1", "timeclass"
//and so on
    event.appendChild(time) document.getElementById("event").appendChild(event)
```

```html
<div id="event"></div>
```

I have tried doing this function, but it displayed an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

Is it possible without jquery?

Comment: The code doesn't have to be a one liner *inside* `elementCreation`, now does it? Keep it on several lines inside there. The shortening comes when *calling* the function.

Comment: @deceze just found that out.  All I had to do was set the `.classList.add(style` to a new line in the function. Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `classList.add` method does not return anything and that is last statement executed. To solved this:

```
function elementCreation(name, style) {
    let event = document.createElement(name);
    event.classList.add(style)
    return event;
}
let event = elementCreation("div", "event")
let time = elementCreation("h1", "timeclass")

event.appendChild(time);
document.getElementById("event").appendChild(event)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `elementCreation` function must be return a `Node`, you're tries to return a `.classList.add` result (which is undefined).  This code works:

```js
function elementCreation(name, style) {
  let element = document.createElement(name);
  element.classList.add(style);
  return element;
}
let event = elementCreation("div", "event")
let time = elementCreation("h1", "timeclass")
//and so on

event.appendChild(time);
document.getElementById("event").appendChild(event)
```

```html
<div id="event"></div>
```

Comment: I figured it out 2 minutes later yes. Sorry for making stupid questions.

Comment: If you want a single-line code, you can use something like that: `(element = document.createElement(name)) && !element.classList.add(style) && element` but it isn't recommend.